# Disable delegate method for UIPickerView/UITableView on conditional case

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I want to disable below delegate method for some condition

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

let say `if(x==YES)` then only above delegate method hit else it won't respond.

Please let me know your suggestion.

Comment: you can just put the if condition inside this method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `respondsToSelector:` and return `NO` in case of You does not want to call this method:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    if (selector == @selector(pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:))
    {
        if(your_Condition)
        {
           return YES;
        }
        eles
        {
           return NO;
        }
    }  
    return [super respondsToSelector:selector];
}
```

So you're implementing the delegate method as normally. When the picker view is asking your delegate if it understands the message you're simply lying to it.

Comment: I could not understand properly how to use this ..! :( 
Elaboration will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do it.

1) Make Delegate Null

Set a condition when you do not want to call the method and at that place make `delegate = nill`.

And again Reset it `delegate =self` when needs to call the method.

The second method which I must say **Better** one

2) Use flag inside the Delegate method

Try to implement if-condition (Flag) inside the method and set its TRUE and FALSE values as per requirement.

for ex.

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
     if(x == YES) {
                // Only this code need to implement
     } else {
     return;
     }
```

}